# jQuery Mobile - back button

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am developing the application using jQuery Mobile 4.1.

In my app, I have two html pages like login.html and home.html. In the home.html have 3 pages. () like menupage, searchpage, resultpage.

The project flow is login.html ---> home.html. In home.html, menupage is displayed as a first page. If I choose the some option in the menupage it will move to searchpage and then resultpage. consider, currently I am in the resultpage. If I press the back button on the mobile browsers (iPhone-safari, Android-chrome) then it moves to the login.html.

But I want to display the searchPage. How to solve this one? is it possible to do this?

[Note : The pages should be in the single html page(home.html).

Comment: I also have the same problem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307727/not-getting-proper-result-on-back-press-in-jquery-mobile). anyone got solution



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307727/not-getting-proper-result-on-back-press-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 68, accepted):

use the attribute `data-rel="back"` on the anchor tag instead of the hash navigation, this will take you to the previous page

Look at back linking: [Here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/forms/../../docs/content/../../docs/forms/../../docs/forms/../../docs/pages/docs-pages.html)

Comment: Ya THanks.. But I want to move the previous page through Browser back button.

Comment: By default the browser back button takes you back to the last page, so why do you need to code this?

Comment: In my sample ,The browsers back button takes me into the login.html when I click the back button on the browser (Note: I am in the resultpage of home.html).

Comment: I could not get it to work @PhillPafford. `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><a href="#" data-rel="back">go back</a>`

Comment: @Dr.DOT Please post a question about this as the example you have provided is a little confusing

Comment: Thanks @PhillPafford. I ended up moving on and using `<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a>`

Comment: It also works if you remove the `href` and only user `data-rel="back"`

Answer (score 18):

Newer versions of JQuery mobile API (I guess its newer than 1.5) require adding 'back' button explicitly in header or bottom of each page.

So, try adding this in your page div tags:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
data-back-btn-text="Back"
```

Example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back">
```

Comment: This one works for me, but how do you add an icon to it? I tried data-icon="back" but the button then disappeared

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('mybutton').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();
        return false;
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('mybutton').click(function(){
        parent.history.back();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this script in the header of HTML code:

```
<script>
   $.extend(  $.mobile , {
   ajaxEnabled: false,
   hashListeningEnabled: false
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nonHistorySelectors option from jquery mobile where you do not want to track history. You can find the detailed documentation here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

This is for version 1.4.4

```
  <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>CHANGE HOUSE ANIMATION</h1>
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all"  data-role="button" role="button">Back</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: you shouldn't add those classes when you set `data-role=button` etc. Most of them are not needed, and those that do stuff should be replaced by proper values of `data-icon` and `data-iconpos`

Answer (score 0):

try to use li can be more even

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#one"  data-role="button" role="button">back</a></li>
 </ul>
```