# Not getting proper result on back press in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi I have 3 html files as

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docs/assets/css/jqm-docs.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="docsdemos-style-override.css" />


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="TestMenu.html" data-role="button" id="myButton">index</a>          

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now on click of button I call TestMenu.html which is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="PortfolioTest.html" data-role="button" id="myButton">TestMenu</a>         

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

on click of button I call PortfolioTest.html which is as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">PortfolioTest</a>         

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I back press then previous screen means TestMenu.html is displayed when I press button again in TestMenu.html it again comes to PortfolioTest.html uptil now everything is fine But now if I press back then instead of going to TestMenu.html it goes directly to index.html page.

This is all when I use Android version 2.2 and if I use version 2.1 then everything is fine. What is the solution for this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;` solve my issue. Now it works perfectly in all version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this messes up your navigation, but you use the same page ID (id="home") for every page. Perhaps you should give the pages different id's.

Comment: @ Jorissu after giving different id for every page also doesn't solve problem

Comment: No, not really, sorry. Thought the above was worth giving a try, but unfortunately it wasn't the fix...

Comment: Any one have idea about this?

Comment: Anybody got solution or suggestion for this?